# find element html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to find element html with Jquery .
in this example element html is "input"

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr2o412y/)

```js
$("#her").click(function() {
  var $t = $('#mee');
  console.log($t.filter());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mee">
<input type="submit" value="click ici" id="her">
```

Comment: your link is not working.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).prev().prop('nodeName');
```

I believe this was the JSFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/sr2o412y/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="mee">
<input type="submit" value="click ici" id="her" >
```

If you want to select a element using jquery you can use (#)id attribute or (.) class attribute or (input) html tagname.

In this case if you want to take the data from text element which has id => "#mee" on click if id => "#her". You can use the below code

```
$('#her').on('click', function(){
    var textvalue = $('#mee').val();
    console.log(textvalue);
});
```

Provide readable id and class names to identify elements properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors looks fine to me. In short, you can use any valid [`CSS` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), so both `$('#her')` and `$('#mee')` should be working in your example, as you have `HTML` elements with those `ids`:

```js
$('#her').click(function() {
  var $t = $('#mee');
  
  console.log($t.val());
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mee" />

<input type="submit" id="her" value="SUBMIT" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to select an element based on its type (tag) instead, then just remove the `#`. For example, to select any input element on the page you would just do:

```
$('input')
```

Or, to get just the first one:

```
$('input').first()
```

Or also:

```
$('input').eq(0)
```

You can also select elements based on type plus attribute to select specific inputs:

```
$('input[type="text"]')
```